# Sharepoint Designer endlessly tries and fails to install

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I only got involved with Sharepoint Designer through trying to install Office Picture Manager, which I got on with quite well years ago.  Now I'm stuck with an infuriating sequence every few minutes of pop-up windows re unfound resources and failed installation. Heaven knows what resources this uses.  Help! W10

Comment: SharePoint Designer was discontinued some time ago, what do you need it for?

Comment: I don't!  I don't need or want it and never intended to have anything to do with it.  I seem to be stuck with this hopeless failed installation looping as a result of trying to get Picture Manager a while back.
Can anyone suggest an uninstall utility that might get rid of these fragments?